# How to estimate velocity from robot_pose_ekf

Tags: ros, differential-drive, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a differential drive mobile robot. and I am using  robot_pose_ekf to estimate the state of the robot [x,y,θ]

How to estimate  [v,ω ] the translational and rotational velocities. from robot_pose_ekf output  or adding   [v,ω ]  as an output from robot_pose_ekf [x,y,θ,v,ω] .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353892/how-to-estimate-velocity-from-robot_pose_ekf/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output topic is http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html which is not providing velocity, I don't think robot pose EKF allows you to do this. Robot Localization however will allow you to do this.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-06-03**:
Are there any individual  package that  can estimate [v,ω ] directly from the output of robot_pose_ekf [x,y,θ], robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined [(geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html)?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-06-03**:
Look at replacing robot pose ekf with robot localization.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-03**:
It sort of makes sense that something called `robot_pose_ekf` doesn't output velocity, doesn't it?